# Return largest of three integers in Java

Tags: java

I am doing these practice quizzes online from CodingBat.com. This is what the question asks of me:

> Given three int values `a, b, c` return the largest.

```
intMax(1, 2, 3) → 3
intMax(1, 3, 2) → 3
intMax(3, 2, 1) → 3
```

So I set up this code and check the results.

```
public int intMax(int a, int b, int c) {
  if(a>b || a>c){
  return a;
  }
  if(b > a|| b>c){
  return b;
  }
  else{
  return c;
  }
}
```

The results showed that my code doesn't work for all cases (although does for most), and the code the teacher had is different.

Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: You are using OR `||`, which is not correct logically. You should be using AND `&&` here.

Comment: Indeed. Consider a = 2, b = 3, c = 1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done:

```
 if(a>b || a>c){
  return a;
  }
```

What if `a>b` but not `>c`?? there you went wrong.

You should use `if(a>b && a>c)` (`&&` instead of `||`) everywhere.

Comment: Oh wow... Makes complete sense. Heh, sorry for what seems like a silly question now. Gonna review those operators! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`if(a>b || a>c)` is considered true if a > b OR a > c. Since you only want to return the value that is the highest of all, you want `&&` which means AND instead of `||` which means OR.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` operator to achieve this.

Because your condition becomes true in false condition.

For ex:

Input: `[5,9,2]`

```
if(a>b || a>c){
  return a;
```

This will give the output `5` instead of `9`.

So use `&&` operator.

```
if(a>b && a>c){
    return a;
}
if(b > a && b>c){
    return b;
}
else{
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` operator instead of `||`

Comment: I dont understand when you say : This does not provide an answer.